# mongodb auth, mongo with user can insert but not mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I'm actually trying to manage multipledatabase connection with mongoengine and python.
So, for the test i've installed one remote mongo server and on local.

version used during test:

- python2.7
- mongodb 2.4.9 (remote)
- mongoengine (branch master)
- pymongo 2.7.2 (used by mongoengine I think)

I've setup a user on the remote mongo with the command:

```
remote $ mongo admin -u admin -p *** --port 7766 
> use test
> db.addUser({user:"toto", pwd:"***", roles:["userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWrite"]})
```

I'm thinking that i give Read and Write on the db i was using, (for the test purpose i did a `use test` before, but I also give to many right with the userAdminAnyDatabase isn't it ?)

Then in mongo i'm trying to insert and then to select, check if everything is good:

```
> db.test.insert({test:"toto"})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54aace23659e51853a6bb3e4"), "test" : "toto" }
```

So far everything seems good, now i go in my python script using mongoengine,
And i'm trying to connect to my databases and save something in each databases

```
from mongoengine import *
import mongoengine.connection

class Test(Document):
  email = StringField(required=True)

class ConnectionTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_double_connect(self):
    c2 = connect("test", "remote", host="mongodb://******/", \
      port=7766, username="toto", password="test")
    a2 = Test()
    a2.email = "remote@remo.te"
    a2._meta['db_alias']="remote"
    a2.save()

    c = connect("test", "local", host="mongodb://localhost/")
    a1 = Test()
    a1.email = "TOTO_TEST_LOCAL@local.host"
    a1._meta['db_alias']="local"
    a1.save()
    print c2.__dict__
    print c.__dict__
```

And if i'm not wrong it's supposed to work, but i get an exception from mongoengine that says i can't insert in test.test:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/depends/mongoengine/tests/test_connection.py", line 33, in test_double_connect
    a2.save()
  File "/Users/lumy-meludia/Meludia/depends/mongoengine/mongoengine/document.py", line 354, in save
    raise OperationError(message % unicode(err))
OperationError: Could not save document (not authorized for insert on test.test)
```

My question is, why this is not working but working well in the mongo interpreter ?

EDIT:
  After Rereading the documentation, and some trouble with azure and the LC_ALL=C
  I discover Where was the fault, and The connection is now Working.

And it's seem that you need to define a new class if you want to interact with a different mongodb with mongoengine.

Comment: Can you be explicit about what database you defined the user on and how you connected to MongoDB using the mongo shell? What was the command line command you used to connect with mongo?

Comment: Thanks, the error was mine, like always, mongodb wasn't listening on the public ip, everything is now working fine.